# How do I restrict some directories to some clients in GlusterFS?

Tags: security, glusterfs

GlusterFS makes it possible with `auth.ssl-allow` option to allow or deny access to given volumes for a given client, identified by its SSL certificate, but the access is global: either the client has access to the entire volume, or not.

It also has [support for ACLs](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator-Guide/Access-Control-Lists/#setting-access-acls) for individual directories, but the ACLs rely on user names, and not SSL certificates. In other words, if a given machine is compromised, nothing prevents an attacker from creating an account with a given name to access specific directories.

Is there a way to restrict access to the given directories to the clients, specified by their certificate's CN?